# how do i access local file shares from a remote computer?

Tags: file-sharing, remote

How do I access local window shares on a remote computer using Windows 7? I've tried Dropbox and Teamviewer but they don't help other than to access the remote desktop. I want to be able to access the files as if they were on the same network as I am.

Comment: VPN might be something to look into

Comment: I see VPN a lot but I only see them to secure an unsecured Internet connection or access otherwise restricted sites. I don't see any thing for just files. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide

Comment: Also, teamviewer can send and receive files.

Comment: Right but I don't want to send and receive. I want to access the files in Windows without any further software. I'm not sure I'm explaining myself right

Comment: You could try forwarding the SMB/NetBIOS ports (UDP 137/138 and TCP 139/445) on your routers so you can access the files from outside, but I wouldn't recommend it from a security point of view. It would allow you to not install any additional software. The more secure option is to use a VPN, which will require the installation of additional software, namely a VPN server (like OpenVPN that I linked to)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to use a remote desktop utility, such as [Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com/product/).